# Is it possible to fix an iPhone app for iOS6+7 and 3.5 + 4 inch displays without editing code?

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, screen-size

At this time I'm trying to edit an app of mine to support iOS6+7 aswell as 3.5+4 inch displays.

However I'm trying to do this without changing the code. And it works fine...for one of my requirements.

First I tried fix the 3.5/4 inch display issue with autolayout/contraints. It worked well but either it looked good with iOS6 or iOS7. And I didn't find a way to fix the iOS6/iOS7 diffrence without adjusting tons of code.

Then I resetted my contraints, disabled autolayout and fixed the iOS6/7 issue via offsets (iOS6/7 Deltas). Worked fine too for resolving the other requirement.

Since you can't use offsets AND autolayout at the same time I'm wondering if it's not possible to fix both problems without either checking iOS version or display size in my code?

I didn't provide code or screenshots because it's a more general question and I'm trying to solve this issue without touching my code. However what I can say is that I'm using .xib files to create the views not knowing if that's a problem too...

Thanks in advance,

blaluma

Comment: Can you elaborate "without changing the code" part? you will have to do little change and depending upon ui you might have to design new xibs

Comment: With "without changing the code" I first meant "without changing the code". :) However since your comment implies it won't work without changing some code it can be understood as "with the least effort". Right know I use offsets to fix the iOS6/7 issue but was hoping there was some ui-attribute I didn't know about which would easily fix the 3.5/4 inch issue.

Comment: If ui is complex then go with diffrent xib for 3.5 and 4 inch

Answer (score 1):

if your using storyboard with autosizing you can achieve that one

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since this option is also available without Storyboard I'm wondering why it should only work using it. However I already tried it without and it didn't work :) Good idea thought but I'm also trying not to switch to storyboard since I'm not the only developer on this app and the other ones won't be happy with said change.